# Kotlin suspendCancellableCoroutine return collection

Tags: firebase, kotlin

I have a problem with corutine. I want ot return in suspendCancellableCoroutine collection of decks. I'm fetching it like this:

```
suspend fun fetchDecksByLanguage(): Boolean {

    val activeLanguage = userService.getActiveLanguage() ?: return false

    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->

        db.collection("Decks")
            .whereArrayContains("languages", activeLanguage)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { doc ->
                continuation.resume(// here I want to return decks collection)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { err ->
                continuation.resumeWithException(err)
            }
    }
}
```

I cant in onSuccess fetch data. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the return type and returning the result from the coroutine should do the trick? Also remember to import the `resume` Kotlin Extension.

```kotlin
suspend fun fetchDecksByLanguage(): List<Deck> {

    val activeLanguage = userService.getActiveLanguage() ?: return false

    val result = suspendCancellableCoroutine<List<Deck>> { continuation ->

        db.collection("Decks")
            .whereEqualTo("languages", activeLanguage)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { doc ->
                continuation.resume(// here I want to return decks collection)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { err ->
                continuation.resumeWithException(err)
            }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: This is good tip, but I nedd to retrun sth here : continuation.resume(// here I want to return decks collection) because now I have returned nothing. Continuation ensure returned value and I dont know how to pass it to resume.

Comment: `continuation.resume(doc)` assuming that `doc` is already of type `List<Deck>`. Also make sure to: `import kotlin.coroutines.resume` at the top of your file

Comment: doc is Querysnapshot but my fun require List<Deck>. And that's the point  with problem :)

Comment: So you were just missing a tiny mapping implementation :)!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution like this:

```
suspend fun fetchDecksByLanguage(): List<Decks> {

    val activeLanguage = userService.getActiveLanguage() ?: return emptyList()

    val result = suspendCancellableCoroutine<List<Decks>> { continuation ->

        db.collection("Decks")
            .whereArrayContains("languages", activeLanguage)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->

                val items = ArrayList<Decks>()

                if (documents != null) {
                    for (document in documents) {
                        val id: String = document.id
                        val name: String = document.data["name"] as String
                        val languages: List<String> =
                            document.data["languages"] as List<String>
                        items.add(Decks(id, name, languages))
                    }

                }
                continuation.resume(items)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { err ->
                continuation.resumeWithException(err)
            }
    }
    return result
```

Comment: you can actually shorten your code  if you use the `map` predicate from kotlin's collections:

```documents.orEmpty().map { Decks(it.id, it.data["name"] as String, it.data["languages"] as List<String>) } 
```